# Remainder modulo matrices.

Tags: matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Is it possible to have a consistent definition of $A\bmod_{left} B$ that respects matrix multiplication from left where $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices with non-negative entries?

Is there a generalized Chinese Remainder Theorem?

We can have $$\lambda B=0\bmod_{left} B$$ 
$$(\lambda C +\mu D)\bmod B=\lambda C\bmod_{left} B +\mu D\bmod_{left} B$$ at every $\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb Z$.

To define $A=LB + C$ we can have $L$ to be the largest integer entried matrix such that $ij$th entry of $C$ lies in $[0,B_{ij}]$.

Similarly we can define $\bmod_{right}$ and $\bmod$ by $A=BR+C$ and $A=LBR+C$ respectively.

Could we impose any additional structure on $K$ and $C$ to make things work?

If all involved matrices are circulant then this works with each of the three definitions agreeing with each other.

Comment: For such a definition, it is sufficient to define which matrices are zero mod $B$. How would you define this? If $B$ is non-singular, then every matrix of the same dimension as $B$ can be said to be zero mod $B$, so that doesn't seem very useful?

Comment: $\lambda B=0\bmod B$ at every $\lambda\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: Are these matrices over reals or integers? I notice that in the question you have $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: look at problem post.

Comment: @AJ I don't see how any of your properties can be described as "respecting matrix multiplication".  They all seem to be respecting multiplication by scalars only, in which case it is just treating the matrices as glorified vectors without any matrix structure.

Comment: @Erickwong $A_1A_2=(L_1B+C_1)(L_2B+C_2)=L_1L_2B^2 +L_1BC_2 + C_1L_2B+C_1C_2=(LB+C)$

Comment: @ErickWong If all matrices are circulant then we have this.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$\mathbf D \in \mathbb Z^{N \times N}$ 
be a matrix with yet-to-be-determined properties. For any two matrices 
$\mathbf A, \mathbf B \in \mathbb Z^{N \times N}$
define 
$\mathbf A \equiv \mathbf B \pmod{\mathbf D}$ if there exists a matrix
$\mathbf M \in \mathbb Z^{N \times N}$ such that
$\mathbf  A - \mathbf  B = \mathbf D \mathbf M$

This is clearly an equivalence relation. In fact, if 
$\mathbf D = \operatorname{diag}(n_1,n_2,\dots,n_N)$, then
$\mathbb Z^{N \times N}/\mathbf D$ is isomorphic to
$\left( \prod_{i=1}^N \mathbb Z/n_i \mathbb Z  \right)^N$

The only problem seems to be the non-negative entries requirement.